# Android Developer Tools 16 and issues with -keepclasseswithmembers in proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I recently installed ADT 16, which is now highlighting a problem that I have the obsolete option -keepclasseswithmembernames instead of -keepclasseswithnames. I've fixed the proguard.cfg file already but lint refuses to recognise the fix and is preventing Eclipse from building the file.

My current proguard.cfg file:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Lint warnings window, select the warning and click the 'Ignore type button' (upper right corner, looks like an eraser or something).

After that, go to http://b.android.com and file a bug.

Update: ADT fails to refresh non-Java and non-XML files, here's the link to the issue:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23196

As newer answers suggest, clicking 'Refresh' will clear the error.

Comment: While this solves the problem of not being able to build, ignoring static code analysis warnings should be done only as a very last resort (and if one knows what he/she is doing). In this case there are other solutions available.

Comment: Sure. What you and other people downvoting this answer don't see is that was the only solution _at the time_. Restarting Eclipse, cleaning, opening/closing, re-importing, etc. _did not_ work. Plus, this is not exactly a static code analysis warning, just a configuration file chek. And I do know what I am doing.

Comment: I agree. But as this is _no longer_ the only solution I find downvoting your answer the only way to make future readers aware of the changes in the ADT since you answered. You could update your answer to avoid that, right? And the remark about "knowing" was oriented towards the knowledge of the original poster, as he might not know about that in depth. Sorry for causing confusion there.

Comment: Anyone can edit answers, this is SO. Anyway, it's done now. As for the  OP, he did fix the file, so there was no harm in ignoring the error.

Answer (score 9):

Just had that same problem. I fixed it by clicking the refresh button in the Lint Warnings window (top right) after changing the `-keepclasseswithmembernames` to `-keepclasseswithmembers` in proguard.cfg.

Comment: This one fixes the error, i have no idea what the accept answer even means.

Comment: It means just what it says: ignore this error to keep it from popping up. Reloading works in 16.0.1, but it has to be done manually, which few people expect. Here's the related ADT issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23196

Comment: I prefer this answer as it actually proposes to solve the issue, rather than to actively ignore it. Ofcourse I agree that the checking should be automatic, but at this time Lint isn't. One other solution is to change the type of the error to a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Just click the "Runs Android Lint" button in the toolbar at top. Generally the button next to "Android SDK Manager"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case your Eclipse build somehow gets confused (like in this situation), you can often make Eclipse get it right again by just using **Project->Clean** (which will cause the build to start from scratch).

At least for me that also invoked Android Lint again and cleaned similar stale error markers.